# Could this Printing Material Recommendation Question be or shaped to be valid on 3D SE?

Tags: discussion, support

[Common 3D printing materials/ methods to suitably replicate (w durability) this injection molded Polypropylene item?](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/8t0ivj/common_3d_printing_materials_methods_to_suitably/)

Please advise. As I am new to 3D Printing and SE Rules can get pretty restrictive on whats allowed or not and would be hard for me to argue or decipher its validity for this SE.

Comment: Whether it is valid or not is a good question. What is actually on-topic is (sort of) up for debate at the moment, see [Game plan - What is on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/game-plan-what-is-on-topic?cb=1). Unfortunately, I don't know whether it is on-topic or not, but hopefully someone does. If you don't get an answer to this question after a few days, I'd post it anyway. If it gets closed, so be it, but you never know, it may be well received.

Comment: @Greenonline - Wow! People are quick to attack questions, but when someone asks ahead of time, there's no guidance. Go figure. PS: I hate the time & energy spent on detailing a question, put all references and then get shot down.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking about your question this morning, and I saw that there were no replies. SE 3D Printing is quite a small site and there aren't an awful lot of regulars here - but there are just enough who can give great answers, but not everyone ventures here, into meta.

I think that you *should* ask the question, it does seem on-topic. If it is well presented (without typos) and has the necessary detail, then it should be OK.  It is usually only very poorly worded, poorly formatted and overly broad questions, where little thought and research has been done beforehand, which are shot down in flames... :-)

Looking at your Reddit post, it seems ok, but it could be worth relevant quoting parts from those links that you listed (as links die over time and the information that you refer to could be lost), and show why or why not, *you* think certain options may or may not be suitable. Your question could also appear to be opinion-based or broad - so it could be better to narrow down your question to a point or two (or three).

If it **does** end up getting closed, which hopefully it won't as you do appear to have put some thought into it, you will be provided with guidance as to how to edit and improve it and make it more suitable for StackExchange.

I wouldn't worry too much, even the best of us have *bad post days* sometimes... it's not a big deal :-)

Also, think about it this way, the time that you take formulating and crafting your question will be well spent as it should help clarify your question in your own mind. Often, I have found, whilst writing and clarifying a question, that I had actually mis-understood the whole issue in the first place, and sometimes re-working a post can help me find my own solution (especially when using peoples comments to adjust the original post), or at the very least, help me get my head around the issue.

---

#### TL;DR - Don't over think this, just post your question :-)

Comment: Just posted - https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/common-3d-printing-materials-methods-to-suitably-replicate-w-durability-this - Please give me some green & support :)