# Is it OK to ask about companies that make 3D printers or related products?

Tags: discussion

It appears that the manufacturer of my 3D Printer may have gone belly up.  Can I ask about that in the 3D Printing site?

Comment: This might be a good time to discuss this further, and I think this should be broken into finer topics about what can be asked about the company itself. Generally, questions related to company's policies are deemed off-topic on SE because it's something that we can't answer officially as consumers.

Answer (score 3):

This could be valuable information for others too, certainly if it is hard to find that the have gone bankrupt. Usually, in the beginning of bankruptcy, it is not clear whether the company can be saved or not. Most of the times they are unresponsive to emails/contact.

On the other hand it is a little off-topic from what we as a community have [defined](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See also [this meta question](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/game-plan-what-is-on-topic).

IMHO we could allow questions about 3D Printer manufacturers.

Comment: only under the ccaveat that we don't a) discuss their policies over speculation or b) rant about them